# Does setting ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no affect the speed with which an SSH connection is established?

Tags: linux

I was curious about the option `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` in the command `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@domain`.

Would setting this option have any affect on the speed with which an SSH connection is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host key is always retrieved from the remote.  The known_hosts file will be be examined to check that you haven't gotten behind a MITM.

The option only really applies when you connect to hosts you have never connected to.  When it doesn't find an entry in the known hosts for the remote you are connecting to, then the key is automatically added to the known_hosts, and you connect.

So the answer is almost certainly no, it won't make any real difference.  I suppose if your system had a horrible write speed, then the updating you known_hosts with the new key associated with a new system might be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and quick answer.  The reason I ask is because the source server is connecting to remote servers that are dynamically launched all throughout the day but if you say the write speed is the bottleneck, then there should be no difference at all

Comment: If you have a strongly secured network, and you are certain there is little or no chance of a MITM, then I believe you can use the `UserKnownHostsFile` config option to `/dev/null` or something.  That way the file will always be empty, and the update will not touch the disk at all.